# Arrangement in a row (2 numbers)

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways in which n '1' and n '2' can be arranged in a row that up to any point in the row numbers of '1' is more than or equal to numbers of '2'.

I tried to solve it using the following logic fix number of '2' and select number of '1' greater than number of '2' but not getting the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics):
$$
C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}
$$

Comment: can you brief about Catalan number

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi That wikipedia article I linked to (where it says "Catalan numbers" in my post) does a better job than I ever could, I think.

Comment: I am working on this problem, can you show me how it works for n=2